# Shell variable substring replacement

Tags: shell

I have a string `Tes$123` and would like to replace with `Tes\$123`.
How can I echo the string with the replacement in Unix?

Comment: Is this string in a file?  A shell variable?  A filename?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ foo='Tes$123'
$ echo ${foo/$/\\$}
Tes\$123
```

We replace here the `$` with `\$`, but because `\` is special, we have to escape it with a `\` of its own.

The construct `${haystack/pin/needle}` will replace the first occurrence of 'pin' with 'needle' in the variable `haystack`.  To replace *all* occurrences of 'pin', you can use `${haystack//pin/needle}`.